# DT::datatable() returns empty widget

Tags: r, dt

For some reason, in one of my shiny projects, `DT::datatable(iris)` returns empty window, even in interactive mode. So, it turns on 'Viewer' tab but nothing shows there. Not sure how to debug it, as in other projects it works fine.

`R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)`

Comment: Did you include it in your UI output?

Comment: Try reinstalling the DT package.

Comment: @camille - yes, and it doesn't work even if I stop the app and try to use `datatable()` in console. @jsb tried - didn't help

Comment: Should it be `DT::renderDataTable(iris)`?

Comment: Sounds silly, but have you restarted your session? Otherwise, it seems like you'll need to post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for anyone to be able to do more than speculate

Comment: Yeah, I did. Also, renderDT doesn't matter, as it doesn't work outside of shiny, too. I'll try to create an example when I'm back to laptop.